# How to open a file using Numpy's genfromtxt but specifying only part of the directory path?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to open a file located in the directory `a/b/foldername_12345678` using genfromtxt. The following works for me

```
file = np.genfromtxt("a/b/foldername_12345678/filename")
```

However, I don't want to keep track of the numbers at the end of the directory path in which the file is located (they are uniquely associated with "foldername"). In other words, I would like to open the file without specifying the full directory path. In linux, I can do this via e.g.

```
cat a/b/foldername*/filename
```

How can I do  the same with genfromtxt?

Comment: You need an additional function for that, e. g. from module `glob`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wildcards with the [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) library.

```py
import numpy as np
import glob

filepath = glob.glob("a/b/foldername*/filename")[0]
file = np.genfromtxt(filepath)
```

The 0 indexing assumes that there is only one possible file that will be found using this wildcard.